# Spring JTATransactionManager fails to bind Hibernate and JDBC in a single session

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jta

I use JTATransactionManager to manage Transactions. One piece of code that I want to wrap with Spring's `@Transactional` annotation has 2 database calls - one using Hibernate SessionFactory and another a plain JDBC. Both use the same dataSource. Hence, I expect both to be bound by the same Transaction.

But it does not look like one Transaction is used. Instead each opens its own Transaction. What could be the reason for this. ? How do I make sure to use a single Transaction to bind both these operations. ?

I can provide configuration and code if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure in both of your database calls, you use propagation as `Propagation.NESTED` as

```
  @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.NESTED)
```

and in the wrapper method, you mention `Propagation.REQUIRED or`Propagation.REQUIRED_NEW` as

```
  @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)
```

or

```
  @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED_NEW)
```

By doing this, you mention that both DB calls will inherit the transaction boundary of the wrapper method.

Comment: I did not work for me.                                       Basically, I annotated the wrapper method in my service with `@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)` and annotated the 2 database calling methods in the same service with `@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.NESTED) `. So the wrapper method calls these 2 methods int he same service. Is this what you suggested ..?

Comment: @AnandHemmige: Yes. Also I think you need to configure spring to use annotation base transaction as `<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>`. Use your transaction manager name in the statement.